# PHP invalid JSON encoding

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

I'm trying to GET a JSON format back when I POST a specific ID to my database. As I get more than one result I have multiple rows, which I want to get back. I do get different arrays back, but it is not a valid JSON Format. Instead of

```
[{...},{...},{...}]
```

it comes back as

```
{...}{...}{...}
```

Therefore the [...] are missing and the arrays are not separated by commas.

My code is down below. The function "getUserBookingsKl" is defined in a different php.

```
//get user bookings
public function getUserBookingsKl($id) {

    //sql command
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `***` WHERE `hf_id`=$id AND `alloc_to`>DATE(NOW()) AND NOT `confirmation`=0000-00-00 ORDER BY `alloc_from`";

    //assign result we got from $sql to $result var
    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

    // at least one result
    if ($result !=null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1 )) 
    {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
        {
            $returArray[] = $row;

        }
    }

    return $returArray;
}
```

...

```
...

foreach($userdb as $dataset)
    {
        $returnArray["group"] = $dataset["kf_id"];
        $returnArray["from"] = $dataset["alloc_from"];
        $returnArray["to"] = $dataset["alloc_to"];

       echo json_encode($returnArray);
     #   return;
    }

    // Close connection after registration
    $access->disconnect();
```

Comment: *”//here pushing the values in to an array”* - No, you’re not.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You can only do one output with JSON, so your actually sending many sets of JSON data not 1.  As a general rule you should be able to call `exit()` after the output and not break your stuff.  If you call exit in the loop, well your loop wont finish, so you have to move that output to after the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're sequentially *emitting* the values, not pushing into an array. You need to make an array, push into it, *then* call `json_encode` on the resulting structure:

```
$final = [ ];
foreach ($userdb as $dataset)
{
  $returnArray = [ ];
  $returnArray["group"] = $dataset["kf_id"];
  $returnArray["from"] = $dataset["alloc_from"];
  $returnArray["to"] = $dataset["alloc_to"];

  $final[] = $returnArray;
}
echo json_encode($final);
```

Note that it's important here to *not* use the same variable inside the loop each time through or you're just pushing the same array in multiple times.